# Linking to external HTML pages in MediaWiki

Tags: html, hyperlink, mediawiki, doxygen, mediawiki-api

I have been generating HTML documentation for my C++ code using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). Where I work, we have a MediaWiki page where we write documentation for a lot of our applications. Since this documentation is auto-generated and is already in a nice clean HTML format, it doesn't make sense to rewrite it to put it on the wiki. All I really need is to be able to put a link on the wiki to the auto-generated HTML.

I have been having a lot of trouble figuring out how to simply put a link to an HTML file in the wiki. It seems like it should be such a simple thing to do, but after doing some digging it really is not very straightforward. I don't even know where to put the file for it to be visible to the wiki server... I'm completely lost.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check with your local sys admin / person responsible for your MediaWiki

Comment: I sent them an email, they're just slow to respond lol

Comment: Please provide a comment with feedback if you downvote so I know why and can update the question if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out [UNC links](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/UNC_links) will work to access HTML files from the Wiki. The files just need to be stored in a location that the Wiki server can see such as a shared drive.

On a side note, in our Wiki, the links only work on internet explorer for some reason. I figured I would at least mention this in case someone else is trying to get this to work on a different browser and running into issues.